# Scrollable dropdown on nav item in Vue

Tags: vue.js, scroll

I am using Vue.js 2.6 and I have a tab reports.

I want to vertically scroll my report options when there are more than three options.

If it helps - all those b-dropdowns are translated to li's with anchors inside when I inspect those in the browser.

```
<template>
  <b-navbar-nav>
    <b-nav-item">
      <router-link to="/logs" class="nav-link">General Logs</router-link>
    </b-nav-item>
    <b-nav-item-dropdown right class="nav-link">
      <template slot="button-content">
        <span>Reports</span>
      </template>
      <b-dropdown-item>Foo</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item>Bar</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item>Foo2</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item>Bar2</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item>Foo3</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item>Bar3</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-nav-item-dropdown>
  </b-navbar-nav>
</template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```css
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100px;
}
```